# Is it possible to vary an LED from low to high brightness at any frequency without MCU?

Tags: led

I am trying to think of way to vary an LED like in a christmas light where it just goes from max intensity to lowest intensity at any frequency without using an MCU. The reason is I don't want to use an MCU is I am trying to make it as small as possible and keep it cheap.

I am not sure yet of how many LEDs I will be driving and at what currents. However, my first attempt at thinking about how I would do it is by varying mosfet with a capacitor on the gate to slowly ramp up the MOSFET and keep it at the linear region longer. However, I don't know how to discharge the cap back to GND.

Comment: You could use a $0.40USD MCU.

Comment: What do you mean "at any frequency"? An ATTiny9 is only about $0.33 and they make them in SOT23 packages.

Comment: those Christmas lights that you mentioned probably have an MCU in each bulb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Use MCU, if the key factor is only price and dimension you can still use couples of MCUs, for example attiny85. It is cheap, small and you can program to it what ever sequence of flashing, dimming or changing brightens you want.

**Solution 2:**

If still for what ever reason you want to stick to analog design you can use 555 timer to get desired functionality. Here is the link for your demand:
[555 Pulse Generator Circuit](https://www.electroschematics.com/pulse-generator-with-555/)

Comment: Yeah I figured that would be the answer. I was hoping the christmas lights have some cleaver analog thing they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Ramp generator with PWM.

From [Pulse-Width Modulator operates at various levels of frequency and power](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3201.html)
[image]

VIN is a potentiometer and PWM Output drives your MOSFET.